# Function calls for URL to turn into image but returns a 403 instead

Tags: python, image, http-status-code-403

I've been trying to find ways to convert the image URL that I had collected from the API I am using, but it's been returning 403 status codes. The URL is a valid jpeg image. Its supposed to take the image of the user's selected album.

```
def getDetails():
    
    url = f"https://api.discogs.com/masters/{albumid}?&key=hidden,secret=hidden"  
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()

    with open("Ex1.json",'w') as file:
        json.dump(data,file,indent =6)

    try:
        image_url = data['images'][0]['uri']
        x = requests.get(image_url)
        print(image_url)

        if x.status_code == 200:
            img = Image.open(BytesIO(x))
            return img
        else:
            print(f"Failed to fetch image {x.status_code}")
            
    except (KeyError, IndexError) as e:
        print(f"Error fetching image: {e}")
```

Here's what it prints:
(with an example input)

> NewJeans - Get Up
> https://i.discogs.com/fh2tUe8Qtjtzt96_CQbRnLj6gpf6I45kP2Xw-UoTVMI/rs:fit/g:sm/q:90/h:600/w:600/czM6Ly9kaXNjb2dz/LWRhdGFiYXNlLWlt/YWdlcy9SLTI3NzM2/NTEyLTE2ODk5MTQ3/NzItOTA0NS5qcGVn.jpeg
> Failed to fetch image 403

Comment: The given example URL appears to work fine, when opened directly in my browser. Why are you trying to request it via your python code, and not directly from the client side?

Comment: You need to provide a unique User Agent string, see the [General Information](https://www.discogs.com/developers#page:home,header:home-general-information) section in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing on the header the **User-Agent**, following [this](https://github.com/jesseward/discogs-oauth-example/blob/master/discogs_example.py), I've managed to get this script using the url that you gave as an [example](https://i.discogs.com/fh2tUe8Qtjtzt96_CQbRnLj6gpf6I45kP2Xw-UoTVMI/rs:fit/g:sm/q:90/h:600/w:600/czM6Ly9kaXNjb2dz/LWRhdGFiYXNlLWlt/YWdlcy9SLTI3NzM2/NTEyLTE2ODk5MTQ3/NzItOTA0NS5qcGVn.jpeg) and get the image that you were trying to download/use

```py
import requests as req

res = req.get("https://i.discogs.com/fh2tUe8Qtjtzt96_CQbRnLj6gpf6I45kP2Xw-UoTVMI/rs:fit/g:sm/q:90/h:600/w:600/czM6Ly9kaXNjb2dz/LWRhdGFiYXNlLWlt/YWdlcy9SLTI3NzM2/NTEyLTE2ODk5MTQ3/NzItOTA0NS5qcGVn.jpeg", headers={"User-Agent":"discogs_api_example/1.0"})
# print(res.content)

with open("x.jpeg", "wb") as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

Replace with your code as needed.